# aspectj get object to within pointcut

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have the following class:

```
package Test;
public class A
{
    private B b = new B()
    {
       @Override
       public boolean someFunc() {return false;}
    }
 }
```

What is the AspectJ pointcut to capture execution of someFunc, and at the same time get a reference to outer class A?

I tried:

```
pointcut captureExec(): within(Test.A) && execution(boolean Test.B+.someFunc());
before(): captureExec()
{
    //here thisJoinPount.getTarget() returns object to class B, 
    //but I need reference object to the outer class A
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
pointcut captureExec(Test.A a): within(a) && execution(boolean Test.B+.someFunc());
before(Test.A a): captureExec(a) 
{
    if(a==blah) ...
}
```

Not tried it though

Comment: I couldn't get yours to compile.  With the following modification: "pointcut captureExec2(Test.A a): within(A) && execution(boolean Test.B+.someFunc()) && target(a);  before(Test.A a): captureExec(a)"  I was able to compile, but got no match...